# best practice - string comparison

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a lookup table with an id and a text value.

What is the best way to check if a value is x or y? Hardcoding the string? Using an "enum"?

EDIT:
What I mean is, is it ok to just do:

```
if (VALUE_FROM_DATABASE == "value x")
then do this
```

What if the values in the database change in the future? I guess there might not be a way around that and we'll always have to change the code when that happens?

Comment: Without more context, this question is very vague and hard to answer.

Comment: Do you mean that your database table has an enum-like structure and you would like to leverage that knowledge in your code as a C# enum, without breaking it when the database values change?

Answer (score 1):

just use simple if:

```
if(value=="myString") {}
```

I do not see here a reason for `Enum`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(String.Compare(string, compareString,true) == 0)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lookup table and you are reading the values from a table, etc you cannot use `switch` statement since it must be a `constant`.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to put a `SystemId` value on any lookup table on which change the way the program works, and then create a matching `enum` to reference it in code (although if I'm using NHibernate, I just use the enum). If I were to be completely <strike>paranoid</strike> strict, I'd create a check constraint and a unique on the SystemId column too to stop anyone adding anything to it without really having to try hard.

Answer (score 0):

### On the enum question (after your edit)

Possibly you mean that your database lookup table has, say, enum-style values "In store|Out of stock|Unavailable". If you want to use enums in your code, you have to jump through some hoops:

1. Create an extra field in the table, this is a sticky field and shouldn't change
2. The other fields (description / name) are allowed to change
3. Create an enum, create appropriate methods in your DAO to make sure that any getter/setter only accepts that enum
   3a. Same is true for other fields in other tables that are referenced to this field
4. Raise exception when a value outside the reach of the enum is stored or found
5. This is quite some work to do by hand, if this pattern comes along more often, automate it with code creation.

---

*Original answer, possibly void after edit of OP:*

Something like:

```
// get your value from the database (don't know what you use now):
string value = lookupTable.GetById(12345).Text;
if(value == "x" || value == "y") 
{
    // do your thing
}
```

But then I'm assuming a lot about your current code, of which you don't show much.

EDIT: you ask whether you should change your code when your database's value changes. No, not needed. Each time your run your code, you retrieve the value from your database, and there won't be a problem.

Comment: What if you change the values x and y for z and w in the databse? In that case you'd have to change the code to compare them with these new values... This was the whole point of my question...

Comment: @user4: your original question didn't say anything about x/y coming from database, but check my update, I think I should understand your question differently. Is this more on track?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how many different values you are comparing with. If one or two, then go a head and use an if statement and the equal sign.

Do not use lots of `if` statements. It might be better to use a `switch` statement then or a `Dictionary` to find acceptable values.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Equals method on strings that you should use for comparison so something like

```
if(value.Equals(stringToCompareTo)){}
```

There is an overload to that method which takes a value from the `StringComparison` enum so if you wanted to ignore the case in your comparison you would do something like

```
if(value.Equals(stringToCompareTo,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){}
```

Answer (score 0):

store that string on the configuration

if (VALUE_FROM_DATABASE == ValueFromConfig)
//...then do this

Comment: to read from the config would be something like (assuming you added a reference to system.configuration and added using System.configuration at the top)

if (VALUE_FROM_DATABASE == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConfigValue"])...